# Tradingview alerts firing if condition is valid for t time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

is there anyway to configure alert or alertcondition on TV to fire if a condition is met for certain time

example:
cond=ta.crossover(close,K)
alertcondition(cond,"C O")
in TV alert can be fired once per bar  or at bar close  once or once a minute
supposing we have set the alarm on 1h TF is there anyway for that alert to fire only if  cond is true for 10 minutes

many thanks

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++